# How to create a pull request from existing repo to a new?

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, bitbucket-cloud

We got 4 separate repositories. Dev, QA, UAT and Prod in Bitbucket Cloud.

[image]

Now we need to add another repo between UAT and Prod. Which will be pulling changes from UAT.

Therefore, I forked UAT and created new repo called Preprod.

But when i try to create a pull request from UAT, I can't select Prepod as target. How do i achieve my requirement ?

[image]

Comment: Have you get the answer which helps you solve the problem? If yes, you can mark the answer. And it will also benefit other members who meet similar questions.

Comment: @ChamingaD, How about this issue? Could you get useful information from Marina's suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to avoid forking:

- clone UAT as a bare repo
- make a new empty Preprod repo on BitBucket Cloud
- push --mirror UAT to it

See "[Mirroring a repository](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/)" (here explained in a GitHub context, but the same idea applies)

Comment: We will be doing frequent pulls from UAT to Preprod. So by creating a mirror, will it appear on pull request target list ?

Comment: @ChamingaD Not sure (to be tested). That was requested before (https://mail.gnome.org/archives/desktop-devel-list/2016-February/msg00054.html) If not, you would need to push your branch to Preprod, and make an intra-repo PR from within Preprod.

Answer (score 0):

For now, bitbucket does not support the feature to create pull request from original repo to fork repo (only the opposite way is supported: pull request to merge changes from fork repo to original repo).

And I create an issue [Enable to create pull request from original repo to fork repo](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/16847/enable-to-create-pull-request-from) to suggest this feature, you can follow up.

The workaround for now is **merging changes from original repo to fork repo locally and then push to the forked repo**. Detail steps as below (such as merge the changes from UAT `master` branch to Preprod `master` branch):

```
#In the local Preprod repo
git checkout master
git remote add upstream <URL for the UAT repo>
git pull upstream master
#Commit conflict files if there has
git push origin master
```

Now in the Preprod repo `master` branch, it contains latest changes from UAT `master` branch.